# Pass Data String as parameter to a Function for HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I know this title seems a bit odd, i couldn't explain it better.

Here is what i need. I have this javascript function and i need to pass the data as a String variable to it:

```
var chart;
function drawChart() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
}
```

I need to pass this data as a parameter to my function

> [
>                       ['Firefox',   45.0],
>                       ['IE',       26.8],
>                       {
>                           name: 'Chrome',
>                           y: 12.8,
>                           sliced: true,
>                           selected: true
>                       },
>                       ['Safari',    8.5],
>                       ['Opera',     6.2],
>                       ['Others',   0.7]
>                   ]

How can i do it?

I want it to look like something like this

```
var chart;
function drawChart(dataString) {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: dataString
        }]
    });
}
```

I have tried solution by @moonwave99 :

```
var browsers = [
 ['Firefox',   45.0],
 ['IE',       26.8],
 {
     name: 'Chrome',
     y: 12.8,
     sliced: true,
     selected: true
 },
 ['Safari',    8.5],
 ['Opera',     6.2],
 ['Others',   0.7]
];
```

and

```
...........
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data:  JSON.stringify(browsers) 
        }]
............
```

And my outcome is this:

[image]

**Solution** : http://jsfiddle.net/USzVy/1/

```
var browsers = [
 ['Firefox',   45.0],
 ['IE',       26.8],
 {
     name: 'Chrome',
     y: 12.8,
     sliced: true,
     selected: true
 },
 ['Safari',    8.5],
 ['Opera',     6.2],
 ['Others',   0.7]
];


function drawChart() {
var data_str = JSON.stringify(browsers);

    var options ={
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: JSON.parse(data_str)
        }]
    }

  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: By no mean you need a string, look at [library API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define your data as an array, not a string:

```
 var data = [["Firefox",45.0],["IE",26.8],{name: "Chrome",y: 12.8, sliced: true,selected: true},["Safari",8.5],["Opera",6.2],["Others",0.7]];
```

Then stringify and pass as parameter to your function:

```
 var data_str = JSON.stringify(data);
 drawChart(data);
```

Then convert to back to JSON

```
 series: [{
        ...
        data: JSON.parse(data)
    }
```

Comment: that's it!!! http://jsfiddle.net/USzVy/1/ You are the man! Thanks all for your help guys!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`JSON.stringify`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
var browsers = [
     ['Firefox',   45.0],
     ['IE',       26.8],
     {
         name: 'Chrome',
         y: 12.8,
         sliced: true,
         selected: true
     },
     ['Safari',    8.5],
     ['Opera',     6.2],
     ['Others',   0.7]
]

...

data : JSON.stringify(browsers)

...
```

EDIT [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDev6/).

EDIT2: I had a look at this [library API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data), and you **don't** need a string, but an array of options! Read the docs and you'll have it done.

Comment: i have tried this `            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data:  { paramName : JSON.stringify(browsers) }
            }]`. The code runs with no errors, the chart frame is loaded but nothing is drawn. I am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Check my latest revision, I added an unnecessary `paramName`.

Comment: please see my latest UPDATE. Something goes terribly wrong with the data

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawChart(data) {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: JSON.parse(data)
        }]
    });
}

var data = "[ ['Firefox', 45.0], ['IE', 26.8], { name: 'Chrome', y: 12.8, sliced: true, selected: true }, ['Safari', 8.5], ['Opera', 6.2], ['Others', 0.7] ]";
drawChart(data);
```

Comment: I have tried this but a get an error `http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14`. I guess this is because i pass the data as string and it it expecting int values :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var chart;
function drawChart(dataString) {
    // options to create the chart
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: dataString // using the parameter
        }]
    };
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
// here you get the dataString some way
var dataString = [
    ['Firefox',   45.0],
    ['IE',       26.8],
    {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 12.8,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    },
    ['Safari',    8.5],
    ['Opera',     6.2],
    ['Others',   0.7]
];
drawChart(dataString);
```

Comment: what do you mean `here you get the dataString some way` ? Thats what i am trying to figure out :)

Comment: I have tried this, and the frame loads fine, but no data is drawn on the chart

Comment: I 've must have tried it but not sure why it didn't work for me. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

Excelent, solutions, i was tryng your codes, but my chart do not show nothing, so, i was tracking my values that i pass like parameters, and my problem was that i sending my values like string, i solve this just converting my data with the parseInt() command.

```
            function graficar(var1,var2,var3,var4){

                    var chart;
                    var datos=[];
                    datos[0]=parseInt(var1);
                    datos[1]=parseInt(var2);
                    datos[2]=parseInt(var3);
                    datos[3]=parseInt(var4);

                    var datos_str =JSON.stringify(datos);

                    alert(datos_str);

                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                                renderTo: 'grafico',
                                type: 'column'
                                },
                        title: {
                                text: 'Titulo de ventas'
                               },
                        xAxis: {
                                categories: ['30%', '40%', '50%', '60%']
                                },

                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                        return ''+
                                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
                                        }
                                },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                               },
                        series: [{
                                name: 'Valores',

                                data: JSON.parse(datos_str)
```

..
..
...

Thanks